# How add existent input text to a dynamically created form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a "static" text input element that not belongs to any form. I wrote a Bootstrap 4 Popover with a form inside, this form is added to DOM when the popover is shown and I validate it with Bootstrap validation. I want to insert the "static" text input into popover form and validate it when form is validated.
I tried to add the `form="form_id"` attribute to input element when the popover is shown (and form is added to DOM) but doesn't work...

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_100">
```

JavaScript code:

```
btn_with_popover.on( 'shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $( '.close-popover' ).on( 'click', function () {
            btn_with_popover.popover( 'hide' );
        } );

        let this_button = $( this );
        let popover_id = this_button.attr( 'aria-describedby' );
        let popover_header_text = $( '#' + popover_id + ' h3.popover-header span.header-text' );
        let popover_body = $( '#' + popover_id + ' div.popover-body' );
        let shortcode = '';

        if ( this_button.hasClass( 'my-class-one' ) ) {
            shortcode = 'class_one_button';
        } else if ( this_button.hasClass( 'my-class-two' ) ) {
            shortcode = 'class_two_button';
        }

        $.ajax( {
            type: 'post',
            url: ajax.url,
            data: {
                action: 'queries_database',
                _nonce: ajax.nonce,
                shortcode: shortcode,
                contact_id: 0,
            },
            success: function ( queried_data ) {
                let options = $.parseJSON( queried_data ).shortcode_options;

                let id_number = 100;
                let form_id = 'popover_form_' + id_number;
                let checkbox_id = 'gdpr_terms_' + id_number;

                if ( shortcode === 'class_two_button' ) {
                    console.log($( '#input_' + id_number ));
                    $( '#input_' + id_number ).attr( 'form', form_id );
                }

                popover_header_text.html( options.title );
                popover_body.html( '<div><p class="text-justify px-1">' + declaration + '</p></div>' +
                    '<form class="needs-validation" id="' + form_id + '" novalidate><div class="form-group text-justify px-1">' +
                    '<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="' + checkbox_id + '" name="gdpr_terms" required>' +
                    '<span class="custom-control-label font-italic" for="gdpr_terms"> ' + options.checkbox_label + '</span>' +
                    '<div class="invalid-feedback">' + __( 'Devi accettare prima di poter proseguire.', 'ccwhatsapp' ) + '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">' + __( 'Avvia conversazione', 'ccwhatsapp' ) + '</button></div></form>' );

                this_button.popover( 'update' );
            },
            error: function () {
                popover_header_text.html( __( 'Si è verificato un errore' ) );
                popover_body.html( '<p class="text-warning">' + __( 'Ops! Qualcosa è andato storto...' ) + '<i class="far fa-tired"></i></p>' );
            }
        } );
    } );

$( '.container' ).on( 'submit', 'form.needs-validation', function( event ) {
        if ( this.checkValidity() === false ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            let checkbox = $( this ).children().find( 'input[type="checkbox"]' );
            let input = $( '#input_' + 100 );

            if ( ! checkbox.is( ':checked' ) ) {
                checkbox.addClass( 'is-invalid' );
            }

            if ( input.val() === '' ) {
                input.addClass( 'is-invalid' );
            }
        } else {
            let href = $( '#my_button_' + 100 ).data( 'href' );
            window.open( href, '_blank' );

            btn_with_popover.popover( 'hide' );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question

Comment: Instead of trying to pass the whole `<input>` into the popover, try adding a duplicate `<input>` in the popover and then populate it with the value from the first input.

Comment: If i add a duplicate `<input>` the validation works for duplicate but not for original...